# How to replace a small halogen bulb in outdoor accent fixture that my fingers barely fit into?

Tags: light

Any ideas on how to replace a small halogen bulb in an outdoor wall accent light. The bulbs are small and the light cups are long and low to my planter I can't see and can barely get my fingers up in them.

Comment: it is unclear what you are talking about ..... please provide a picture

Answer (score 2):

**You need a suction cup**

Electrical lighting fixtures with recessed bulbs often come with a suction cup. It's a odd device to have in the package if you don't realize it's purpose so they often get thrown away with the packaging. Fast forward a year or two and you need to change the bulb.

**That's where these come in handy**[image]
www.amazon.com

You simply push it against the bulb and twist. They come in a variety of styles and even come with extensions to change ceiling fixtures from the floor without a ladder or stool.

Comment: although any suction cup will do, I'm impressed this vendor asks $25 for a suction cup with a straight face.

Comment: i don't see how that would work at all on a tiny push-in halogen bulb; there's little surface area on such bulbs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be talking about the really small, friction fit halogen bulbs, that are somewhat long and skinny. These just get pushed into the socket, rather than twisting them in, and are just held in by friction.

I have had to deal with these in car interiors, and found a great way to get them in and out is with a small piece of tube or hose that fits snugly over the bulb. If you already have the replacement bulb, you can see if you have some hose laying around that fits, otherwise, take it to the hardware store or automotive store and see if the vacuum or fuel hoses will fit.

Then you just take your piece of tubing, push it in the light fixture so it slips over the bulb, and then pull it out. And do the same in reverse to get it back in. Same concept as the other answer with the suction cup, but this may work better for this specific kind of bulb.

Comment: I have used this method with both 2 straight connectors (pins) and push and twist. The import and thing is to clean the tube and not touch the lamp with fingers when putting in the tube (any oil may cause the lamp to overheat and pop, or just shorten the life). The other method I use is a western union lamp removal tool. A tool with 2 metal 1/2 tubes that clamp the lamp , but most are larger and tubing is available in more sizes.+